# Content Security Policy issue when using auth0 with heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, auth0

I'm trying to get auth0 to work with heroku, but having some difficulties.

I can get it to work locally without issues, but it just wouldn't work with Heroku

My setup:
React app which is being server from express as a static resource

Code for auth0 provider:

```
const providerConfig = {
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Auth0Provider {...providerConfig}>
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Auth0Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The error I get when I try to login:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://small-dust-7659.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 needs to know about your origin, so it can allow cross-origin (CORS) requests to be made from your site on Heroku.

There's a detailed description on how to set this up [here](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/applications/set-up-cors).

Basically on your [applications](https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications) page you can set up your origins and URLs.

Comment: Thanks! but I have already configured this on the app settings page and I can connect without issues from httpo://localhost:3000 (if I remove this, I get a different error that the callback URL isn't allowed)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with helmet configuration..

I added the auth0 domain to connectSrc and it solved the issue

```
    helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            objectSrc: ["'none'"],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "unpkg.com", "polyfill.io"],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "https: 'unsafe-inline'"],
            ----> connectSrc: ["'self'", "xxxxxx.eu.auth0.com"],
            upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
        },
    },
});
```